# How to add buttons in text?

Tags: discussion, support

How to Add a Button like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in the text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>`.

See https://askubuntu.com/editing-help for more help about markdown editing.

Comment: Thanks bro, it worked :)

Comment: An 8k rep user should know what should be posted on meta and what should be posted on main.

Comment: @hbdgaf You will see soon that I was first that I closed this question in this sense. However, the question requires an answer even if it is here or on meta.

Comment: @hbdgaf Now you can see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/324378/how-to-input-buttons-in-answers-in-ask-ubuntu?noredirect=1 ;)

Comment: @RaduRădeanu - point well made.  consider that redacted, except that it was already answered on meta.